# I can't embed images anymore?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

Suddenly, when I try to embed an image, it only puts the link in. (Just like if you have less than 10 rep)

I'm curious if any other users are experiencing this... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... switching to Google's DNS server seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe your DNS was broken.  [tag:status-norepro] now, though.

Comment: I had the same issue. Thanks for sharing!